# How can I restore Google Chrome settings from last Windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, bookmarks, restore

My Windows was crashed and I installed another Windows, but I have full access to all my last Windows' files. Can I use them to access only bookmarks and not even history, passwords, settings, etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you logged in with a google Account on your old PC, it restores your Bookmarks and other setting if you login again.

Alternatively you just copy your old Chrome Files from:
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
to the same location on your new PC.

In the subfolder C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default should be a bookmark File which you could restore for only bookmarks.

Comment: in **AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default** I don't see any relevant file about bookmark. Can you help more?

Comment: In the Folder should be a bookmarks and a bookmarks.bak File. Copy these 2 to your new PC in the same Folder. Rename your current 2 Bookmark Files, for recovery reasons if something goes wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are not such files there. My system was heavily corrupted. I had installed a portable Chrome that might had interfered with default Chrome. I have even search all my files with Everything and found nothing but bookmarks.bak in my portable Chrome, but that is not what I want as I couldn't use it at all because My Chrome was crashing during last Windows and for a while I was using Safari (even Firefox wouldn't work).